# Need a page that shows all articles that are published within a folder

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In sitecore, I have a folder full of articles. I update these every quarter. Then I have to go to another page and manually link to all of these articles. I want to know if there is a way to automatically list these articles on another page. For example, if the folder has 10 articles, but only 9 are publishable, then my main landing page will only show the 9 published articles, but not the 10th one. Make sense? Sure I can manually do this, but there has to be a way to make this more automatic.

Comment: Can you change your code to use all the children of the selected folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's go through it in more detailed view - couple of notes to Mark's answer. In real production environment you would likely have at least 2 servers - authoring (content master or CM) and content delivery (CD). Youк Sitecore desktop is running on CM only and publishes items to CD database. You will have a copy of your website code running on CM (for at least doing Page Previews) and on CD where in fact your website is.

Items that are only published come to CD database so having code from above

```
var folder = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("your-folder");
var children = folder.GetChildren();
```

running on CD will iterate through published items there (those 9 of 10).

Same code running on CM (let's say in page preview mode) will show you all the items (10 of them), unless you have this items in a workflow assigned AND do explicitly check workflow status while iterating and process only items in a specific state (final for instance). That code might look something like below:

```
IWorkflow workflow = item.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);

if (workflow != null)
{
    WorkflowState state = workflow.GetStates().FirstOrDefault(state => state.DisplayName == workflowStateName);

    if (state != null)
    {
        // check the state according your requirements and append to collection
        var children = folder.GetChildren();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this requires code at all.... I know some other CMS's you can do this just by manipulating out of the box configuration, or via some extra plugins. Is code really the only answer to this?

Comment: I afraid, yes. On Sitecore demonstrations they usually show how nicely you can create a page within a minute just by manipulating visual components, publish it and try and see immediate result. he reality behind this is even let's assume you have a visual component that simply iterates and lists child items (that you want easily to drop on a page), the one still needs to be pre-created by someone, and that process requires encapsulating the logic with the code. Even if it is very trivial with one line, it still needs to be there. Sorry to disappoint you on that ...

Comment: Bummer... thanks for the answer anyways. Were might I place this code if I wanted to try this?

Comment: Garek, can you please tell me what are you using - Webforms or MVC?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand you correctly. But here goes.

```
var folder = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("your-folder");
var children = folder.GetChildren();
```

While simplified, from what you describe there really is nothing more to it. On a normal website, your context database will be "web" and only the 9 publishable articles will be there. Whatever is "unpublishable" never makes it to here.

If there are more twists to this, I think your question needs more information.

Comment: Mark thanks for the answer. I think that's right, but I don't know where to paste the code. I also thought it might be simpler, not requiring code. I thought it may be something you could do with simple configuration.